# Can't boot into Windows 7 from GRUB

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, grub, bootloader

So a while ago I installed Ubuntu.  I was hoping I would be able to use Windows boot loader to choose between Windows 7 and Ubuntu every time I booted, but no Linux had to install GRUB.  After a while of me never using Ubuntu I got upset by GRUB making me select Windows every-time, so I went to try and remove it.  I got a program called testdisk http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk to try and make my windows partition bootable.  This actually didn't work and now I can't even use GRUB to boot to windows, I can only use Ubuntu.  Great...

So now I have GRUB and and can't use windows.  My computer didn't come with a windows 7 disk, but I made a system repair disk and a system image disk.  When I boot from the repair disk I get some weird text in German (i think).  When I use GRUB to boot from Windows 7 recovery, I get an error saying that RDVD folder wasn't found.  I just want Windows back and Linux gone forever.

Comment: Your doing most of it wrong. You could have edited the grub file to have default windows as the choice rather than removing it and messing up the system. 

Any ways, with out recovery stuffs. Is the grub working fine? You can boot linux? What happens if you select windows option.

Comment: @zenwalker grub works fine and I can use boot linux.  When I select Windows I just get and error.  If I press a key the screen go black and says something like 'F014c:' or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a program called [Super GRUB Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) to boot into your windows partition even if the MBR is messed up.

After you are in windows, you can then re-write the MBR to just have windows (or to have whatever you want) by using a helpful program called [EasyBCD](http://download.cnet.com/EasyBCD/3000-2094_4-10556865.html?tag=posts;msg3325506).

**Update:** Another option is to use a Windows Install disk, and select repair install. It might help to click to find drivers to see if you files/filesystem is still intact.

Comment: When selecting Detect any OS, I got a bunch of error: unrecognised fs, and then my only option to boot from was linux

Comment: Are you sure the windows partition is still intact?

Comment: nope.... at this point I don't care if everything on my computer is destroyed, I just want windows back... I would just reformat the whole thing, but I don't have a windows 7 Install disk... just 3 System image disks, but I don't know if I trust to use those.

Comment: If you have access to another computer that has windows installed, you can create a recovery disk (see [here](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/create-a-windows-7-system-repair-disc/))